# how to check if user already exist with same email or phone number while registration in Cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

when new user register with same email and phone number user successfully registered in the Cognito user pool. so how can i check if user already exist with same email or phone number while registration in Cognito user pool

This is my code for user registration in Cognito user pool

```
result = client.sign_up(                                                
            ClientId= clientId,                                                 
            Username= data['username'],                                         
            Password= data['password'],                                         
            UserAttributes=[                                                    
                {                                                               
                    'Name': 'phone_number',                                     
                    'Value': data['phone_number'],                              
                },                                                              
                {                                                               
                    'Name': 'email',                                            
                    'Value': data['email'],                                     
                },                                                              
                {                                                              
                    'Name': 'custom:usertype',                                 
                    'Value': data['userType']                                  
                },                                                             
            ],                                                                  
            ValidationData=[                                                   
                {                                                              
                    'Name': 'custom:usertype',                                 
                    'Value': 'required'                                        
                },                                                             
            ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListUsers API call (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) to filter users by their attributes and if it comes back with results, then you can handle user validation.

You can also contain this logic in the "Pre-Sign-up Lambda Trigger" to centralize server-side validation logic: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Answer (score 0):

We have the same scenario.
I also need to prevent users to sign up with same e-mail and/or phone number.

In our case, we have a service a `User Data Service` which stores user related data including the e-mail and phone number (this is duplicate data with Cognito).

Since we already have this `Service`, I preferred using this one rather than fetching the list of Cognito Users and looping through them (Imagine if you have thousands or more of users, that would cost a time to fetch and a time to loop)

What I did is request a method to our `User Data Service` to valid if an e-mail or phone number already exist.

I created a lambda for doing the validation and set the lambda a `Pre-sign up trigger`.

`Pre-sign up trigger` is also triggered for users who signs up via Google or Facebook so it will prevent them to sign up if their e-mail already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not storing your users in external database, you can catch an UserExists exception like this:

```
try:
    client.sign_up(
        ClientId = os.getenv('app_client_id'),
        Username = user.email,
        Password = user.password,
        UserAttributes = user_attributes(user)
    )
    return {"Success": f"User: {user.email} created!"}
except client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException as e:
    return {"Error": "Email already exists!"}
```